# Avoid duplicates in concatenated list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have scenario where i want the invoice numbers from two tables in csv list. I could accomplish this using Stuff as below:

```
SELECT
   sopnumbe
  ,custname 
  ,Invoices = 
        STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ RTRIM(a.sopnumbe)+', '+ RTRIM(B.sopnumbe)
               FROM 
                  SOP10100  a
                  fULL OUTER JOIN 
                  SOP30200 B
                  ON a.ORIGNUMB =B.ORIGNUMB
               WHERE a.ORIGNUMB =@ordernumb
               FOR XML PATH('')) , 1 , 1 , '' )
FROM SOP10100
WHERE
    SOPNUMBE = @ordernumb
```

The above query produces right results except for the repetitive invoice numbers in the list. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

---

```
if the result of simple outer join query is:

INV1527157              INV1523836        
INV1527157              INV1526475
```

---

---

the result of stuff query:

```
K08081383206      BACHELOR CONTROLS INC    INV1527157, INV1523836, INV1527157, INV1526475
```

---

INV1527157 gets repeated, i want to get rid of repetition.

Comment: Just a general comment, you might want to clean up the formatting to make the code easier for others who don't know it, a little bit easier to read perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try `UNION` the results together from `A` and `B`, rather than a full outer join:

```
SELECT ', '+ RTRIM(sopnumbe)
FROM (SELECT sopnumbe FROM SOP10100 a WHERE a.ORIGNUMB = @ordernumb
      UNION
      SELECT sopnumbe FROM SOP30200 b WHERE b.ORIGNUMB = @ordernumb
) RESULT
```

This will return only the distinct results from both subqueries.

Comment: Sorry, I was just providing an example I did not try it.  It should work if you wrap it, like SELECT * FROM (Select blah union select blah 2).  Do you get some kind of error, or why doesn't it work?